# Image tab jquery onclick and mouseout function

Tags: jquery, html, image

I am working on Image Tabs only not the `<ul><li>` tabs,

There are images `a.png` and `a-h.png`, `-h` represents the hover image.
We have 3 images side by side acting as tabs.
But i user `mouseout` function, the click function goes out ie the hovering of the active tabs is removed.

below is the html code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="TabMenu">
        <span><img src="images/a.png"></span>
        <span><img src="images/b.png"></span>
        <span><img src="images/c.png"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And below is the jQuery Code

```
$(".container .TabMenu span").mouseover(function(){
var myRegExp = /-h./;
var myRegExp2 = /-h-h./;
var str1 = $('img', this).attr('src');
var match = str1.search(myRegExp);
var match2 = str1.search(myRegExp2);

if(match == -1 ){
    var newSrc = $('img', this).attr('src').replace(".", "-h.");
    $('img', this).attr("src", newSrc);
}
else if(match2 == -1){
    var newSrc = $('img', this).attr('src').replace("-h-h.","-h.");
    $('img', this).attr("src", newSrc);
}
});

$(".container .TabMenu span").mouseout(function(){
var myRegExp = /-h./;
var myRegExp2 = /-h-h./;
var str1 = $('img', this).attr('src');
var match = str1.search(myRegExp);
var match2 = str1.search(myRegExp2);

if(match != -1){
    var newSrc = $('img', this).attr('src').replace("-h.", ".");
    $('img', this).attr("src", newSrc);
}
else if(match2 != -1){
    var newSrc = $('img', this).attr('src').replace("-h-h.", "-h.");
    $('img', this).attr("src", newSrc);
}
}); 

$(".container .TabMenu span").click(function(){
var myRegExp2 = /-h./;
var newSrc = $('img', this).attr('src').replace("-h-h.", "-h.");
$('img', this).attr("src", newSrc);
});

$(".container .TabMenu span").click(function(){
var myRegExp2 = /-h./;
var newSrc = $('img', this).attr('src').replace("-h-h.", "-h.");
$('img', this).attr("src", newSrc);
});

});
```

When I hover on clicked image then move out of the clicked image, the active stage stage ie `-h` of the image is moved out..
How can we implement this, hover, active and I used regex expressions to avoid the hovering mouseout on clicked image.

Comment: I'm looking for this image stuff!

Comment: Just wondering, why not use `$('a').hover(function()`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well what do you want, but try by this way instead of regex :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="TabMenu">
        <span><img class="state1" src="images/a.png"><img class="state2" style="display:none;" src="images/a-h.png"><img class="state3" style="display:none;" src="images/a-h-h.png"></span>
        <span><img class="state1" src="images/b.png"><img class="state2" style="display:none;" src="images/b-h.png"><img class="state3" style="display:none;" src="images/b-h-h.png"></span>
        <span><img class="state1" src="images/c.png"><img class="state2" style="display:none;" src="images/c-h.png"><img class="state3" style="display:none;" src="images/c-h-h.png"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And jQuery :

```
$(".container .TabMenu span").live("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).find("img").hide();
    $(this).find("img.state2").show();
});


$(".container .TabMenu span").live("mouseout", function(){ 
    if($(this).find("img:visible").hasClass("state2")){
        $(this).find("img").hide();
        $(this).find("img.state1").show();
    }
    else if($(this).find("img:visible").hasClass("state3")){
        $(this).find("img").hide();
        $(this).find("img.state2").show();
    }
});

$(".container .TabMenu span").live("click", function(){ 
    if($(this).find("img:visible").hasClass("state2")){
        $(this).find("img").hide();
        $(this).find("img.state3").show();
    }
    else if($(this).find("img:visible").hasClass("state3")){
        $(this).find("img").hide();
        $(this).find("img.state2").show();
    }
});
```

So, is it correct ? :

- state1 OR state3 > mouseover > state2
- state2 > mouseout > state1
- state3 > mouseout > state2
- state2 > click > state3
- state3 > click > state2